# Umbraco Front-end UI with Devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress, umbraco, devextreme

I'm using Umbraco V10 and I want to add some Devexpress component to my front-end page of Umbraco website.

I have followed this document to add the package : https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNetMvc/8163/getting-started/integration-into-aspnet-mvc-project/manual-integration-into-an-existing-project#step-6-attach-the-required-style-sheets

But it still seems not to recognize the devextreme component to draw some default chart https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPNetCore/Demo/Charts/StandardBar/
Have anyone succeed to implement Umbraco with Devexpress?
If it's possible can i have simple example of it please?
Thank you.